# Launching an Android APK file from my Application

Tags: android

I have a requirement wherein I have to launch another apk file from my assets or SDCARD of the device from my application. Is this feasible ? If yes, How ?

Comment: I think we can install an .APK file and we can launch an installed app. What is your actual requirement ?

Comment: @YugandharBabu I want to launch an .apk file from the assets folder

Comment: @RajeevNB What you want to be happen after launching your .apk file ?

Comment: I juts want to launch is it possible ? How ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to launch an application from within your android app. This thread might help: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/android-launch-an-application-from-another-application)

For easy reference's sake here is top answer (courtesy of andep):

If you do not know the main activity, the package name can be used to start the application.

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

Comment: Can we know the package name of games like angry birds ?

Comment: If you have a copy of the .apk,just open it as a zip file and look at the AndroidManifest.xml file. The top level <manifest> element will have a package attribute.

Comment: If the answer is satisfactory please do mark it as correct using the check mark :) Thanks!